# Did Blender 2.9 remove sticky option from floor constraint?

Tags: animation

I used to rely on "sticky" features in floor constraints to make feet grip floor. Is that now gone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This option has been removed in 2019 [as indicated here](https://developer.blender.org/rB533e267e95cf1115eebde95a67dc3b05d48e6ffd) by Sergey Sharybin.

> Remove Sticky option from the Floor constraint
>
> This option from the very beginning of its existence needed more work
> to make it work correct and this was never done.
>
> This option was working fine during continuous playback, when there
> are no skipped frames, but it was failing when AV-sync of framedrop
> was enabled. It was never working correct when jumping between frames,
> including rendering on a farm which usually does frame-range based
> rendering.
>
> With copy-on-write things became even more tricky, since the "stuck"
> flag was never preserved between re-evaluations.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. I often hit snags and jerks with it.